# How to make sure JS file runs in external php without including again?

Tags: javascript, php, include

I have a PHP script that includes a .JS file. The PHP file makes a jquery call to an external `functions.php` file which requires the same .JS file, however, with it being a separate file, I have to include it again inside `functions.php`. If I do this, it breaks the first include, but the 2nd include works. If I remove the include from the external file, the script doesn't work, but everything in the original file does.

Is there a way to include a JS file in the external file without calling it again? Can it just call from the first include?

Included as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using php's [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)
should resolve your problem. This function ensures that the given file will only be included once.

Comment: Idk if that will work in this particular situation. The first time it's included, is in a 3rd party program I'm writing a module for. I can't change the first include, only have control over the 2nd.

Comment: @CrunchyToast using include_once it will check if it is already included so if you don’t have access to the first invlude it should not matter.